# How to store array data as map key or increment frequency if array already in map?

Tags: c++, qt, stdmap, stdarray

My code:

```
map<array<byte, aes>, int> possible;
array<byte,aes> temp;

if (!possible.count(temp)) // if not found
    possible.insert(pair<array<byte,aes>,int>(temp,1)); // insert
else
    possible[temp]++; // if found increment frequency
```

I need to use an array with its data as a map key. An integer indicates the frequency of occurrence of the array. However, the new array is only written the first time, the other times the code considers it to be the same array. As I understand it, the program takes the address of the array, not its data. How to pass an array with data to the map instead of the address of the array?
I know that in Qt this code works fine:

```
QMap<QByteArray,int> possible;
QByteArray temp;
if(!possible.count(temp)) // if not found
    possible.insert(temp, 1); // insert
else
    possible[temp]++; // if found increment frequency
```

What is alternative for std::array and std::map to do this?

Comment: in addition to the answer, calling `count` and `insert` is redundant. `insert` already tells you if the element was present or not before the insert took place, and when it was nothing is inserted

Comment: *As I understand it, the program takes the address of the array*, that's not true. The array is copied (or moved) into the map.

Comment: @john, but when I try to print map.size() it always prints 1

Comment: @keepky That's because the size of the map is one. What number were you expecting. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Unless there's any initialization happending between the declaration of `temp` and its use, the contents of the array uninitialized resulting in undefined behaviour of the code. `std::map` does not compare the address of the array: there are comparison operators implemented for `std::array<int, ...>`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_cmp Of course if this is the exact code you're using, you'll deal with a new map object every time your program executes this section of the program logic.

Comment: @fabian but initialization is happending. This code placed in for loop. Each loop temp array has a new data. I need to write this data as map key, if it doesn't exist. If this data is already exist, I need to increment frequency

Comment: @keepky Either you are asking for something really weird, or you are mistaken about the way this code is working. I can't figure out which (although I suspect the latter).

Comment: @keepky This code works in exactly the way you described in the comment to fabian.

Comment: @keepky Maybe you should show the code, including the loop.

Comment: @keepky I don't see how you can get an answer useful to you without adding a [mcve]: You claim the array is initialized and you may be right or you may be wrong about that. The same map object could be reused or you could be using different objects. You not initializing the array contents and using different map objects is what the code snippet in the question would behave,unless there's code missing from the question.A small code snippet showing this kind of info would greatly improve the question quality,bonus points,if it's a snippet <30LOC that actually compiles and doesn't need user input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ this code will work fine

```
possible[temp]++;
```

If `temp` exists then it's frequency will be incremented. If it does not exist then it will be inserted with a frequency of 0, which will then be incremented. This gives you exactly the same result as your code.

Looking at the documentation for QMap, it seems the above code would also work on Qt.

Sometimes (not often) things are easier than you imagined.

Comment: Yeah, it works the same. Thank you.
But the problem still remains with the fact that only the first array is inserted. In other cases, the frequency is incremented. How to refer to an array so that the array data is written to the map, instead of the address?

Comment: @keepky You want the new key to overwrite the old key even though they are exactly the same? Why?

Comment: This code is placed in for loop. Each iterate my array have new data. I need to write this data in map, if it doesn't exist. If it exists, I need to increment frequency.

Comment: @keepky That's what this code does. Can you say precisely what operations you are performs and what you expect the map to look like afterwards.

Comment: @keepky I think the most likely thing is that your code has a bug. You think the problem is the way the map is updating (because to you that's the most complex part of the program) but really the bug is that your data isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @keepky If you use this code on two different arrays (I mean two arrays with different bytes) then the size of the map will be two. If that is not what you are seeing it's because you don't have two different arrays.

Comment: Really, my code has a bug. I need to find amount of ones in array. After that all arrays are empty.

for (int j = 0; j < aes; j++)
  {
   while (temp[j]) {
    ones += temp[j] & 1;
    temp[j] >>= 1;
   }
  }

Comment: @keepky So you are saying that your code zeros the array before adding it to the map, and you didn't realise? Oh well, problem solved!

Comment: can you help me? How to count ones in array data without creating copy of array and so that array won't empty after that?

Comment: @keepky in C++20 [`std::count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count), before a simple loop. It is unclear why you think you need to modify the array to count its zeros

Comment: @keepky Something like `for (int j = 0; j < aes; j++) { for (int k = 0; k < 8; ++k) { ones += (temp[j] & (1 << k)) != 0; } }` **untested**

Comment: @john. Something is wrong. This code calculates over 4000 of ones. But the array is 128-bit. Therefore, there cannot be more than 128 ones.

Comment: @john sorry, now your code works absolutely fine!